# How to export Pagetree of all pages on a website in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm responsible for one of my company's websites. The English is awful and I need to go through every single page and correct/rewrite the content.

I want to export the pagetree, the list of all pages, from TYPO3 ideally into excel or any spreadsheet program so that I can easily keep a running list of what I've done and what remains.

I realize worst case I copy and paste directly, but that's messy. Is there a better solution?

Running TYPO3 v6.2.14

Answer (score 1):

You can install the phpmyadmin extension from TER and export the queryresult of all pages.
The SQL command would be like:

```
SELECT root.title as Rootpage, subpage.title as Subpage 
FROM pages as subpage
INNER JOIN pages as root
ON subpage.pid = root.uid
WHERE subpage.deleted = 0 AND subpage.hidden = 0
ORDER BY subpage.pid
```

It lists all pages with it's parent page that are not deleted nor hidden. You can adjust it the way you need. You will find the export button on the very bottom of the result view. Then just export as csv, which should be the default, and import it in Excel or LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: I would advise to not use the TYPO3 phpmyadmin extension, and instead install phpmyadmin separately on a well-protected virtual host. Historically the phpmyadmin TYPO3 extension has had more security problems than any other extension. Best solution if you can: use the commandline SQL tool on the server or connect a client via SSH.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have the rights to install extensions nor will I get them. I'm responsible for all the content, etc, but don't have full admin =( I guess I'm doomed to copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

Use the importer/exporter , which can be accessed in the right-click contextmenu.

Comment: Tried that but it doesnt export the entire pagetree with the hundreds of other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use Web > Info-Modul > Pagetree Overview and set them to Infinite. Copy/paste the list from screen to Excel or Open Office table. Delete unwanted columns.

Comment: Yup, that's been the best method so far sadly.